# Sudo asks for password, even the ssh key method is setup for newly created user

Tags: debian, debian-bookworm

I have an issue with the Debian server- When I use sudo with the newly created user it asks for a password, and it's already setup for ssh login(which is working fine as I can log in to the server).

My steps are below

- Created Debian vm in Digital Ocean, selected ssh key based login - it's working
- Created a new user and added to sudo group, and setup ssh login key-based method -it's working fine
- So I can log in to the server with the new user, but when I tried to use the sudo from the new user terminal, it asks for the password. However, my need is it should not ask for the password as I am using key based login.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your key-based login is *for SSH,* and **sudo is not SSH** – it's a completely separate tool that just happens to be used *through* a remote SSH connection in this case.

Although it is technically possible to set up sudo in such a way that it would use SSH keys, it's certainly not a common configuration (and on top of that, it only works if your SSH client has "agent forwarding" enabled – which creates a security risk by itself, yet without it remote programs have no way of knowing what keys you have).

Passwordless sudo is more often implemented by disabling its authentication completely. If you have access to systems with passwordless sudo, check if they have the `NOPASSWD:` option listed in /etc/sudoers or in the `sudo -l` output.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! In AWS I used to work this way as there is no password asked for sudo, but in Digitalocean the vm is provided the  root user and when I create a new user this occurs. Could you please guide me to achieve this or some online articles I can read?

Comment: @RintoGeorge: It is much more likely that sudo in your AWS images was set to _no_ authentication at all, not SSH key authentication. Look for the `NOPASSWD:` option in /etc/sudoers (or in `sudo -l`).

Comment: Let me check that way